# Is there any reason to post a message to the main looper inside an onclick handler in Android?

Tags: android

I am looking at some code that someone else wrote in Android.  They wired up an onclick listener, and inside it, put some code to post a runnable to a handler that runs of the main looper.  Like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

...

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                //code
            }
        });
    }
});
```

To me, this looks like a complete waste of time because both the onClickListener and the Handler are running on the main/UI thread.  Is there any conceivable reason to do this?

Edit:  Let me provide more detail...

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

...

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                someListener.onComplete();
                ((ViewGroup) ((Activity) getContext()).getWindow().getDecorView()).removeView(someFrame);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would you even do that.? Its not required.

Comment: Dude, I don't know;  I think the person who wrote this code is a moron, but I want to make sure I'm not just suffering from the Dunning–Kruger effect.

Comment: There are a few cases where this makes sense. One that I've seen is for code that requires a layout to happen before the code can execute properly. If a layout is requested, you can then post a Runnable that will execute after the layout pass happens.

Comment: I believe the button can be clicked only when it is on the screen ie. after the layout has happened.??

Comment: Sure, in this case it probably doesn't make sense. In theory if clicking the button resized the layout, it is possible that this is required. I'd be hesitant to immediately throw the code away as unnecessary without seeing what it actually does.

Comment: Already looks like a bit of a hack, removing views from the decor views through that chain. I'd bet some issue showed up that required this -- I'd suggest not removing the code that posts to the handler, but if you feel you need to refactor, see if there's a better way to accomplish whatever that button is doing without having to access the decor view through a bunch of casting.